# Warning export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported when using -compile([export_all]) in Erlang Program

Tags: erlang

While writing my erlang program i used "-compile([export_all])." in my header as I read in many online materials which will handle all the export functions.
But when I compile the file I get Warning Saying this 
" Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported"

Could anyone help me here to remove this warning ?

-compile([export_all]).

Comment: I think you should keep this warning on. By default it doesn't prevent the compilation to complete, and it is a good pratice to select the functions that must be exported and those which have only a local usage.

Answer (score 6):

You can add 1 more `nowarn_export_all` compile option like below:

```
-module(foo).
-compile(nowarn_export_all).
-compile(export_all).
```

However, you should just export main functions that you want to use from other modules. `export_all` is used when you test or debug